# Memory allocation increased when playing a remote video using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

When playing a remote video via URL the memory allocation of my app is increasing substantially.

How can I reduce that memory allocation?

Comment: What is a URL allocation of memory?

Comment: its from url means and on seeing in instuments its  allocation memory is geeting increased very much

Comment: Got you now - will take the freedom to reword things a little...

Comment: how to reduce that allocation any sugesstions